# How to run Putty "RET" command in the Batch file

Tags: file, batch-file, putty

I'm trying to use Putty to pull Laser Emission hours from IPG lasers and I wanted to automate the steps to a Batch file which will outputs the Laser hours when I run it.I was able to complete step 1 which is to start,tip host ip address,the port number and select raw. Setp 2 is when click "Open",a DOS window will appear where the command "RET" needs to be tipped in and  hit enter.And the laser emission time appears.Where do I set the batch file to enter the command "RET" in the DOS window? Thanks

Comment: [The Windows command prompt is *NOT* a DOS prompt!](https://scalibq.wordpress.com/2012/05/23/the-windows-command-prompt-is-not-a-dos-prompt/)

Comment: You are right.Thanks for the rectification

Answer (score 0):

Do not use PuTTY (GUI application) to automate tasks. Use Plink command-line tool (part of PuTTY package). It is a console application, so you can redirect its input.

For example:

```
(
  echo RET
) | plink.exe -raw example.com -P port
```

See also related [How to execute remote command using PuTTY over Telnet](https://superuser.com/q/914643/213663#914660).